# Adding meta data to user

Tags: 7, users

I would like to store meta data about users.

At first this I tried by adding fields to the user, but this is not exactly what I want, because the user himself should not be able to manipulate or view the data.

The data I want to store is based on actions a users takes in the application. Its is similar to a status which I want to write and read programmatically. E.g. has the users phone number been validated by the system?

What is the best way to store such data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields are definitely the best method for storing this data.

You can combine fields with the [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module:

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

With that module you'll be able to specify exactly which fields the user should be able to view/edit.